# How to apply breakpoints in AWS AMPLIFY STUDIO in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, responsive-design, aws-amplify

How to make a responsive component build by AWS amplify from figma file

I tried to make it responsive using breakpoint but unable to do. Expecting the same.
How to use useBreakpoint hook and what are the steps to make the component like Header to make it responsive on every device

Comment: You need to add a variant named breakpoint. Create variants using the breakpoint values: base, small, medium, large, xl, and xxl. Then adjust the variants per your requirements.